# Rails, a lot of fields in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I work with `RoR`.

I have two forms with fields:

```
FormA: Name(uniq), Field 1..30
FormB: Name, Field 1..40

FormA belongs_to FormB
FormB has_one FormA
```

Name in the `FormA` it is text_field, but Name in FormB it is `collection_select(FormA.all).`
If i have `FormA` with name "`XYZ`" than i i have `XYZ` in drop down menu in Form B.
But if there is no `XYZ` in `FormA` I dont have `XYZ` in drop down menu of FormB.
Very often `FormB` is created earlier than B, and i cant chose name , becouse the name is not there. Firs I have to create `FormA`.

How to resolve this to create `FormB` without name in `FormA`.
Maybe third model Names name:string and in both `FormA` and `FormB` dropdown list with names?
Maybe one big model, not two, Model1, Model2.

How it should looks like?

Comment: are you using postgres or other? if other please mention in question.

Comment: please R&D on pg extensions like "hstore ". This will solve your problem.

Comment: Fields1..30  means that i have always 30 fields in FormA, not 2 or 7 or 30 fields, and the same situation with FormB